# Alignment in a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am using the following `DefaultTableCellRenderer` to display currency in my tables. It works fine too, only problem I have is, the numbers in the columns I set this renderer on are aligned left, everything else is aligned right. I´d like to know why.

```
public class DecimalFormatRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

public static final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    value = formatter.format((Number) value);
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
}    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default cell renderer used by `JTable` to render numbers set's it horizontal alignment to `JLabel.RIGHT`...

```
static class NumberRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer.UIResource {
    public NumberRenderer() {
        super();
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    }
}
```

You render will be using `JLabel.LEADING` by default (being based on a `JLabel`).

If you change your renderer to set the horizontal alignment in constructor, it should align to where you want it to go...

```
public class DecimalFormatRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    //...

    public DecimalFormatRenderer() {
        super();
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    }

    //...
}
```